# Does Brahmcharya break even by masturbation or only by sex or touch of a woman?

Tags: sex

Does Brahmcharya break even by masturbation or any type of ejaculation (like night fall) ?

Or Does Brahmcharya break only by having sex or by touching a woman ?

Comment: Touching a woman might not cause violation of brahmacarya because it would imply that touching the feet of the gurupatni causes loss of brahmacarya.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of Brahmacharya.

**Brahmacharya (celibacy) for monks**

> Not indulging in sexual intercourse, mentally, verbally or physically
> is the vow of celibacy, with reference to the ascetics and the
> religious students.

**Linga Purana I.8.16**

> Abstinence from sexual acts, neither brooding nor imagining about it
> and complete sexual detachment is called celibacy (Brahmacharya).

**Vayu Purana I.59.46**

**Brahmacharya (celibacy) for householders**

> In their case, as prescribed, indulgence in sexual intercourse with
> their wives and abstention from it with other women mentally,
> physically and verbally should be understood as brahmacharya.

**Linga Purana I.8.18**

Brahmacharya is broken by masturbation. Non-sexual touching of a woman (like handshake) is Ok.

**Wet Dreams do not break Brahmacharya vow**

> **One's vow of Brahmacharya is not broken by having wet dreams.** In such
> cases the expiation laid down consists in the pouring of libations of
> clarified butter on the blazing fire.

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section XXXIV-XXXV**